# Angular 6 - To deploy App in production

Tags: angular, deployment

I am trying to upload my first Angular App to production, I have executed the command:

```
ng build --prod --build-optimizer
```

Next I copied the contents of the dist folder in the root directory of the server folder.

I am seeing the application correctly, the only problem is when I reload the page in the browser, it gives me the following error:

```
Not Found
The requested document was not found on this server.
```

In the index.html file I have the base tag in this way:

```
<base href = "/">
```

And this is my routes file:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'writer', component: WriterComponent },
  { path: 'music', component: MusicComponent },
  { path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/404'}
];
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: You'll need to configure the server a little bit as well https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

Comment: First, you don't need the `--build-optimizer` argument, it defaults to `true` now. Second, your application is an SPA (single page application), which takes care of the routing, as opposed to the server in a regular website. So you need to redirect every url to the index.html so that Angular can take care of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this has to be configured on the server. Please refer to here: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Without knowing what type of server you are deploying on I can't be specific.

Comment: I think it's Apache, I'm going to review the server and the link that you posted, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to get the Exactly folder of your project.

```
ng build --prod --base-href /FOLDER_NAME/
```

Answer (score 0):

copy the index.html file and paste it in same directory and name it 404.html